# AutoPickBundleSelectionCriteria in v1811

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working on a PoC with the Configurable Bundle Module on v1811, I configured a very basic BundleTemplate with one package and two components, each one with one product, one has a PickExactlyNBundleSelectionCriteria with N=1 associated and the other one with an AutoPickBundleSelectionCriteria.

I expect that once I start the bundle (selecting the pick 1 product marked as a starter) the second component marked with the auto-pick was going to be added automatically to the cart and bundle. But this is not happening.

In order to have available the AutoPickBundleSelectionCriteria ItemType, I had to add the subscriptionbundleservices extension to the localextensions.xml.

Am I missing some point?

Answer (score 0):

This criteria is disabled by default. To enable it, you need to add a property as:

```
configurablebundleservices.autopick.enabled=true
```